# How create the frequency table with multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, frequency, contingency

I am trying to make a frequency table with multiple columns.
My data is

```
C = as.factor(sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(rep(1/2, 2))))
R1 = sample(c(-1, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)
R2 = sample(c(-1, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)
R3 = sample(c(-1, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)
data = data.frame(R1, R2, R3, C)
rowb = expand.grid(data.frame(r1 = c(-1, 1), r2 = c(-1, 1), r3 = c(-1, 1)))
```

My goal frequency table is that row contains a combination of **rowb**, and column is **C**. 
At this time, **R1, R2**,and **R3** are matched with the row. 
If no match is found, the value of the element is zero.

I attached a structure for goal frequency table.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what your expected output is?  What is 'A' and "B' in the image showed

Comment: Perhaps `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(data), R1+R2+R3~C, length)`

Comment: Thank you, akrun! My question was a bit inaccurate...

Answer (score 4):

Based on the image you provided, it seems you just want to create a new variable concatenating R1-3 and then tabulate it with C; you could just use `paste()`:

```
data$comb <- factor(paste(data$R1, data$R2, data$R3),
# make sure the levels are in the right order:
                    levels = paste(rowb$r1, rowb$r2, rowb$r3))

table(data$comb, data$C)
```

output

```
            A  B
  -1 -1 -1  5  5
  1 -1 -1   6  4
  -1 1 -1   6  5
  1 1 -1    8 10
  -1 -1 1   7  4
  1 -1 1    9  5
  -1 1 1    5  7
  1 1 1     4 10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` and join with 'rowb'

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), R1+R2+R3~C, length)[rowb, on = .(R1=r1, R2 = r2, R3 = r3)]
```

Or do the join first and then `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(data)[rowb , on = .(R1=r1, R2 = r2, R3 = r3)], ...~C)
```